# New to scientific python. I'm getting an AttributeError: 'ImmutableDensNDimArray' error and I don't understand why

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

**I recently got accepted to grad school and my PI works with python and wanted me to learn how to use it through a series of exercises. I was given an equation and told to make it work. But I am getting an error and I just can't see why. Here is the portion of the code that causes the problem (I included the values of each summation function and the numeric sequence as comments since I did not include the code for the functions):**

```
import scipy.optimize as sciop
import sympy as sp
import math as mt


#Calculates coefficients and builds the function     
def Function(x, raw_input, N):
    sequence_numeric = sequence_numeric_value_parser(raw_input) #[0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0]
    Q_summation = Q_Summation(sequence_numeric) ##-0.0011654102397665102
    O_summation = O_Summation(N) ##-3.7169446884230575
    B_summation = B_Summation(N) ##16.674533284328376
    FiTC = 3/2 ##1st term constant
    STC = ((3/(2*mt.pi))**(3/2))*O_summation ##2nd term constant
    TTC = 0.1*((3/mt.pi)**3)*(1/16)*B_summation ##3rd term constant
    FoTC = (7.2/3.8)*mt.sqrt(6/mt.pi)*Q_summation ##4th term constant
    funct = FiTC*(x-sp.log(x)) + STC*x**(-3/2) + TTC*x**(-3) + FoTC*x**(-1/2)
    print ("x = {} , funct = {}".format(x,funct))
    return funct


#Minimizes function
def Minimizer():
    x = 1.0
    result = sciop.minimize(Function, x, args=(raw_input, N))
    print("Minima at: ")
    print("x = {}, funct = {}".format(result.x, result.funct))

Minimizer()
```

**The error I get is:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Richard Miller\Desktop\A2v0.2.py", line 184, in <module>
    Minimizer()

  File "C:\Users\Richard Miller\Desktop\A2v0.2.py", line 178, in Minimizer
    result = sciop.minimize(Function, x, args=(raw_input, N))

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 604, in minimize
    return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 1003, in _minimize_bfgs
    old_fval = f(x0)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 327, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))

  File "C:\Users\Richard Miller\Desktop\A2v0.2.py", line 167, in Function
    funct = FiTC*(x-sp.log(x)) + STC*x**(-3/2) + TTC*x**(-3) + FoTC*x**(-1/2)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py", line 473, in __new__
    result = super(Function, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **options)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py", line 288, in __new__
    evaluated = cls.eval(*args)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\functions\elementary\exponential.py", line 659, in eval
    coeff = arg.as_coefficient(I)

AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'as_coefficient'
```

**I've uploaded the full file I wrote to: https://github.com/rmiller415/A2**

Comment: You show a `scipy` import, but the error occurs in `sympy` code.  What are the `sympy` imports and setup?  Using `sympy` with `numpy/scipy` is an advanced topic. I don't think a beginner should be trying to use them together.

Comment: Good to know, I just read that sympy.log was better than math.log and I'm not sure why. So, I replaced the sympy with a math.log and now I'm getting a ValueError, so it looks like that fixes it and I just need to set bounds to keep x from going less than 0.

Comment: Since you are using `scipy` I'd suggest using the `numpy` functions rather than `math` ones.  Use `import numpy as np`. and use `np.log`, `np.sqrt` etc.  And spend some time reading the intro docs for `numpy`.

Comment: The error is being thrown because `x` is a ImmutableDeseNDimArray and SymPy `log` cannot take the log of an array, only a value. What is `x` suppose to be? If minimize turns it into a 1x1 array then in your function you could unpack it as x[0], perhaps or x[0][0].